# HTTP Status 500 - Servlet.init() for servlet spring threw exception here is my code

Tags: java, spring-mvc

controller,service and dao are in different package UserSer interface and UserService class is on package com.service UserDa interface and UserDao class is on package com.dao and Controller is on Package com.controller please help me with this , if i am doing this all on the same package its working but for different package its not working

thankyou

```
@Controller
public class UserController {
@Autowired
public UserSer userSer;
@RequestMapping(value="/get")
public  void dummytest()
{           
System.out.println(userSer.SayHii());
}
}

@Service("UserSer")
public class UserService  implements UserSer{
@Autowired
public  UserDa userDa;  
public String SayHii() {
return userDa.Say();
}
}
@Repository("UserDa")
public class UserDao implements UserDa {
public String Say()
{
return "hiiiiiiiiiiiii";
}
}



  web.xml
   * <servlet>
            <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>
                org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
            </servlet-class>
            <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        </servlet>
        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>*
spring-servlet.xml
*<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:ctx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd
">
<ctx:annotation-config></ctx:annotation-config>
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
<ctx:component-scan base-package="com.controller"></ctx:component-scan>
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping" />
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter" /> 
 <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
</bean>*
```

Comment: you've mentioned only the `controller`  package and so only classes in that will get scanned by spring

Comment: thanks its working now